# How to initialize string from array of char pointer values (char* ptr[])

Tags: c++, arrays, string, argv

str is string, ptr is array of char pointers. I need to initialize str with values contained in ptr.

```
void help(char* ptr[]) {
    cout << ptr[0];
    cout << ptr[1];
    cout << ptr[2];
    cout << ptr[3];
    string str = ptr[0];
    cout << endl << str << endl;

}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char arr1[] = "Hello";
    char arr2[] = "Hi" ;
    char arr3[] = "Blah";
    char arr4[] = "Blah";
    char* ptr[4];
    ptr[0] = arr1;
    ptr[1] = arr2;
    ptr[2] = arr3;
    ptr[3] = arr4;
    help(ptr);
}
```

Comment: What do you want that string initialized to? An array of `char*` is a bunch of strings not a single one, as you seem to know already.

Comment: What do output do you expect?

Comment: do you want to concatenate each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly what you need is the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>
#include <cstring>

std::string help( const char * ptr[], size_t n ) 
{
    size_t len = std::accumulate( ptr, ptr + n, ( size_t )0,
                                  []( size_t acc, const char *p )
                                  {
                                    return acc + std::strlen( p );
                                  } );

    std::string str;
    str.reserve( len );

    str = std::accumulate( ptr, ptr + n, str,
                           []( std::string &s, const char *p ) -> std::string &
                           {
                            return s += p;
                           } );

    return str;
}

int main() 
{
    const char * ptr[] =
    {
        "Hello ",
        "Hi ",
        "Blah ",
        "Blah "
    };          

    std::cout << help( ptr, sizeof( ptr ) / sizeof( *ptr ) ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Hello Hi Blah Blah
```

Comment: I'm wondering why not begin/end idiom instead (which is also C++-ish)?

Comment: @Nawaz Where are you going to use begin/end?

Comment: `help ( ptr , ptr + sizeof(ptr)/sizeof(*ptr) );`

Comment: @Nawaz  First of all see the declaration of the function.

Comment: I saw that already. You're **not** using the *same* signature anyway. All  you needed to make the second parameter `char*` as well (or better `char const*`).

Answer (score -2):

This should work.

```
char ptr[] = "Hello";
string str(ptr);
```